# MongoDB Java driver: check if an $and filter is empty

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a very specific question regarding MongoDB Java driver. In detail, I have an `$and` filter built dinamically from my application. If the array of filters associated to the `$and` is empty, I obtain the following error:

> bad query: BadValue: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array

To resolve this problem I want to eagerly check if the `$and` filter is empty. I have a `BSon` object in my hand. I can transform it in a `BSonDocument` using the following code.

```
filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry())
```

The problem is that I cannot find a standard method to check if the body of the document is empty. Method `isEmpty()` returns `false`, because the `$and` filter is present. Then, I tried to use this approach:

```
filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry())
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> {
          final BsonValue value = entry.getValue();
              if (value.isArray())
                  return value.asArray().size() == 0;
              return false;
          })
      .count() != 0;
```

The above code sound like a code smell. Is there a standard way to accomplish this task? The version of Mongo I am using is 3.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
BsonDocument andFilterDoc = filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry())
```

For checking if `$and` filter doc is empty.

```
andFilterDoc.get("$and").asArray().isEmpty()
```

Comment: So there's not an API *escamotage*, isn't there?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. This is how close you can get without having to iterate.